# How to switch to existing window after closing the current window in Selenium Automation using java

Tags: java, testing, browser, selenium, automation

Actually, i'm trying to switch the control from current window to existing window after closing the current one in Selenium Automation using java. Is there any way to do that. I'm able to control the newly opened window, doing some process & closing this one. Later i just need to move to already existing browser window.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I use , this checks for all the open windows and then switchess control to the next window with an option to close out the older window.

```
protected final void switchWindows(boolean closeOldWindow) {
    final WebDriver driver = checkNotNull(getDriver(), "missing WebDriver");

    final String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    checkNotNull(currentWindow);

    // switch to first window that is not equal to the current window
    String newWindow = null;
    for (final String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        if (!currentWindow.equals(handle)) {
            newWindow = handle;
            break;
        }
    }

    // if there's another window found...
    if (newWindow != null) {
        if (closeOldWindow) {
            // close the current window
            driver.close();
        }
        // ...switch to the new window
        driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just know selenium js webdriver have a api like `driver.switchTo().window(windowName)` could help us move to another window. I am not so familiar with Java API but they are all from almost same invoking way. hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this-

```
        private void handleMultipleWindows(String windowTitle) {
        Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();

        for (String window : windows) {
            driver.switchTo().window(window);
            if (driver.getTitle().contains(windowTitle)) {
                return; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an utility method to switch to the required window as shown below

```
public class Utility 
{
    public static WebDriver getHandleToWindow(String title){

        //parentWindowHandle = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
        WebDriver popup = null;
        Set<String> windowIterator = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandles();
        System.err.println("No of windows :  " + windowIterator.size());
        for (String s : windowIterator) {
          String windowHandle = s; 
          popup = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().switchTo().window(windowHandle);
          System.out.println("Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
          System.out.println("Window Url : " + popup.getCurrentUrl());
          if (popup.getTitle().equals(title) ){
              System.out.println("Selected Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
              return popup;
          }

        }
                System.out.println("Window Title :" + popup.getTitle());
                System.out.println();
            return popup;
        }
}
```

It will take you to desired window once title of the window is passed as parameter. In your case you can do.

```
Webdriver childDriver = Utility.getHandleToWindow("titleOfChildWindow");
```

and then again switch to parent window using the same method

```
Webdriver parentDriver = Utility.getHandleToWindow("titleOfParentWindow");
```

This method works effectively when dealing with multiple windows

Answer (score 0):

Once you closed the current window, you will be seeing the parent window.
To switch back to your parent/previous window you can use the following commands,

- driver.getUIWindowLocator().switchToFirstWindow();
- driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

commands. I think this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please do following code for switching back to base window or original window.

```
String vBaseWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();

    for(String temp : windows)
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(temp);
    }

    // Do code for new window

    driver.close();     
    driver.switchTo().window(vBaseWindowHandle);
```

For more information about how to handle Windows and popup in selenium please go to below URL.
https://trickyautomationworld.blogspot.in/2018/03/how-to-handle-windows-in-selenium.html
https://trickyautomationworld.blogspot.in/2018/03/how-to-handle-popup-in-selenium.html